# Swift 3.0 or Swift 2.3 minimum system version requirement and is it deployed in iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, osx-elcapitan, xcode8

Swift 3.0 is coming up with Xcode 8, what is the minimum iOS / OS X system version required to use Swift 3.0? Is that swift 3.0 support iOS 7 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimum OS X to run Xcode 8 which is compatible with Swift 3 is OS X 10.11.4 (OS X EL Capitan)

[image]

And I think Swift 3 does not support iOS 7

As you have minimum target in Xcode 8 is iOS 8.0

[image]

And as per App Store support measurement iOS 8 (11%) and iOS 9 (84%) better that you stop support for iOS 7 as per my opinion. iOS 10 is coming soon.

[image]

Comment: I understand that minimum deployment target is iOS 8.0 as per Xcode listings. Is it mandatory to set deployment target to iOS 8.0 or higher in Xcode-8?

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick Yes. It's Must.

Comment: but you can change it manually to 7.0 or less. won't it work ?

Comment: Swift 3 *does* technically support iOS 7, but you won't be able to test it with Xcode: you'll need to export as .ipa and install manually or through iTunesConnect. I'm downvoting because I saw someone taking this post as a reference for missing support for iOS 7.