# DISPATCH_TIME_NOW in swift 3 and Backward compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

In accordance with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/5654848) brilliant answer on the usage of `dispatch_after` by @matt, I tried the code on the playground and it works fine (no errors). But when I try to do a backward compatibility as `DispatchTime.now()` is available only for `iOS 10` only like so:

```
func delay( _ delay: Double, closure: () -> ()){
    guard #available(iOS 10, *) else {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
        return
    }
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.after(when: when, execute: closure)
}
```

The compiler offers to fix the `DISPATCH_TIME_NOW` to `Replace "DISPATCH_TIME_NOW" with "dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)"` and throws an error saying

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'dispatch_time_t' (aka 'UInt64')

I tried fixing it as the compiler offers but finally ended up with more errors. How should I use the backward compatibility here? What wrong I'm I doing? Do help, thanks!

Comment: `let when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay)`

Comment: Have you tried if  `DispatchTime.now()` runs on iOS 9? Some availability annotations are wrong.

Comment: why you need check iOS10 to use swift3 syntax? swift3 is really support for iOS lower version like 7 8 9. If you want to compile in new Xcode8 with swift3, just write only code in swift 3 syntax. all your code you need:  func delay( _ delay: Double, closure: () -> ()){
    DispatchQueue.main.after(when: DispatchTime.now() + delay, execute: closure)
}

Comment: @MartinR no I've not checked on a phone. I just tried it in playground and I got those errors. When I command clicked on the 'DisptachTime' and 'now()' , it said available in iOS 10 and macOS 10.12. So I thought I'll try API availability and then these errors showed up. :(

Comment: @Dershowitz123: As I said: the availability annotations are sometimes wrong. The Swift 3 code should run on all platforms where Swift 3 is available. – `dispatch_after` is Swift 2 and won't compile in Swift 3.

Comment: So what do i do in case I am writing an app for both iOS 10 AND <iOS 10.0 platforms too? How do you suggest I modify this @MartinR? :(

Comment: @Dershowitz123: Swift 3 runs on iOS 8 and later. If you want to compile for iOS 7 then you have to use Swift 2.2 with Xcode 7.3.1, and then we are talking about *source code compatibility*, not API availability. Is that what you are really asking for? But keep in mind that Swift 2.2 and Swift 3 are *very* different (and most iOS devices run iOS 8 or later).

Comment: `DispatchTime.now()` is Swift 3 so It will work for iOS 8, 9, 10. It will not support iOS 7 or previous versions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092144/swift-3-0-or-swift-2-3-minimum-system-version-requirement-and-is-it-deployed-in/38092257#38092257

Comment: @AshishKakkad, Swift 3 does support iOS 7. I've added a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

`DispatchTime.now()`, as well as almost any `DispatchQueue` or `DispatchTime` method, is available for iOS 7, 8, 9 and 10. Documentation is simply incorrect.